# Drop down menu doesn't work how I want it to

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a menu which contains one menu-item with a dropdown, however I can't seem to get it quite right.
I started off with combining my existing menu bar to a piece of code for a dropdown, I have managed to get de drop down item in the menu bar, but I don't know how to get the menu bar back to the top again and it still has a blank on the left. 
There is also an extra empty item in my drop down menu and I don't know how to get rid off it?

Can someone please help me I feel like I am overlooking something

```css
.menu-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #134c95;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.menu-item {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 15pt;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.menu-item:hover,
a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: 234c95;
}

.menu-bar a {
    color: white;
}

.menu-bar a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.menu-bar a:link,
.menu-bar a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*
.menu-bar a:hover {
    color: #134c95;
}
*/


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: white;
    /*  padding: 16px;*/
    /*  font-size: 16px;*/
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */


/*
.dropdown {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
}
*/


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /*  z-index: 1;*/
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #234c95;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: 234c95;
    color: white;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: #234c95;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
        <a href="instructiestest.html">
            <div class="menu-item">Welkom</div>
        </a>
        <a href="instructie2.html">
            <div class="menu-item">Aanmelden Portbase</div>
        </a>
        <a href="instructie3.html">
            <div class="menu-item">De App</div>
        </a>
        <a href="testing.html">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">
                    <div class="menu-item">Het team</div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
                        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                        <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `a` tag from your `dropdown` item, like below:

```
<div class="menu-bar">
    <a href="instructiestest.html">
        <div class="menu-item">Welkom</div>
    </a>
    <a href="instructie2.html">
        <div class="menu-item">Aanmelden Portbase</div>
    </a>
    <a href="instructie3.html">
        <div class="menu-item">De App</div>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">
            <div class="menu-item">Het team</div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
                <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, your `.dropdown-content a:hover` rule is missing a `#` in your `background-color` attribute:

```
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #234c95;
    color: white; 
}
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8q6g8uo/)

Comment: Thankyou :) I always have that when I code for a couple of hours I tend to overlook the small details like the hashtags. And finally that empty link is gone!

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to have an extra margin or similar. Try to load the code, and check with the inspector. It'll show you the different spacing types in nice colours: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_the_box_model

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently the margin was automatically set to 8px so I've changed it to 0px and it doesn't have a margin anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, you might be better re structuring this menu completely. I don't mean to be harsh but the code isn't structured well enough and is a little confusing to work with.

Ive just tweaked your code a little to make it easier to work with. I'm not exactly sure what it is your trying to achieve but here is something for you to take a look at:

**CSS**

```
#menu-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #134c95;
    padding: 15px;
}

#menu-bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#menu-bar ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;    
}

#menu-bar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

#menu-bar ul li a:hover {
    color: #134c95;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#menu-bar ul li ul {
    display: none;  
}

#menu-bar ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="menu-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="instructiestest.html">Welkom</a></li>
        <li><a href="instructie2.html">Aanmelden Portbase</a></li>
        <li><a href="instructie3.html">De App</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="testing.html">Het team</a>
            <ul>
            <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
            <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
            <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">YouTube</a>    
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see this is much easier to understand and follow. The ID of the nav element is all you need to style the child elements.

Hope that helps as a starting point!